# prove whether function is continuous or not?

Tags: functions

$f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function with $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

1.The function is continuous in $a$ $\in$ $D$ if:

$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists g>0)(\forall x \in D) [|x-a|< g \to |f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon]$

2.$f$ is continuous on $D$ if $f$ for all $a$ $\in D$ is continuous in $a$

How do we prove or disprove whether this function is continuous?

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \frac{2^x-1}{x-1}$

at $a=1$

Comment: What happened to poor ol' $\delta$?

Comment: You haven't told us what $f(1)$ is. It must be something because you are stating that $f$ is a map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How? You show that $f$ does (or doesn't) satisfy 2. Do you mean to ask about a specific step of examining $f$ with 2?

Comment: Not that is matters, I suppose -- this $f$ can't be made continuous at $1$.

Comment: There's also a chance the first $\Bbb R$ was meant to be a $D$ that suits this particular $f$.

Comment: Could someone privide a general approach to this expression? Thx a lot

Comment: Downvote for the seeding: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650250/how-to-prove-whether-that-function-is-continuous

Comment: @Squirtle Especially with a new user, they might not be aware that this is strongly discouraged; it might be better to leave a comment, and reserve the downvote for later.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @T.Bongers 50 days, 22 questions.

Comment: downvote is ok with me :) @Did, sorry I missed that part that there is a limit for questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as we discussed in the comments [of your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649997/how-to-solve-for-continuous-functions/650051#comment1369289_650051), a function cannot be continuous at a point that is not in its domain. In particular, $$\frac{2^1-1}{1-1}$$ is undefined, so we cannot even talk about continuity of $f$ at $1.$ In order to have $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ we will have to define $f(1)$ separately from the given rule, and you have not given us this information. If they didn't give it to you, either, then the function isn't continuous at $1,$ but since they say that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ I suspect that they *did* say something like "and $f(1)=y$" for some (possibly specific) number $y.$ However, even then, we will have a(n essential) discontinuity at $1.$ To see this, note that $2^x-1$ is positive whenever $x$ is positive, so we can make $|f(x)|$ be as large as we like, just by letting $x$ be sufficiently close (but not equal) to $1.$ (Why?) Now, pick any $\epsilon>0$ you like, and use the alternative triangle inequality $$\bigl||u|-|v||\le|u-v|$$ with this information in order to show that no matter how small we make $c>0,$ we can find $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<c$ and $|f(x)-f(1)|\ge\epsilon.$